# Between dates or latest value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below tables:

I need one row for CID when I join to TableB.

Join Criteria:

Table A CID Start_dt is between AreaStart_dt

If the above does not  match use the latest AreaStart_dt when tablea.cid = tableb.cid

TableA

```
CID    Start_dt    End_dt
 1      1/1/18      
 2      5/1/18
```

TableB

```
CID    Areaid    AreaStart_dt    Area_End_dt
 1      101         1/1/18         1/1/3000
 1      102         1/1/17         12/31/17
 2      201         4/1/18         4/29/18
 2      301         3/1/18         3/30/18
```

Output:

```
CID  Start_dt  End_dt   Areaid
 1     1/1/18            101
 2     5/1/18            201
```

SQL:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM TABLEA A
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY B.CID ORDER BY AREA_START_DT   DESC) RNK
            FROM TABLEB B
               )TABLEB B ON A.CID = B.ID BETWEEN B.AREASTART_DT 
               AND  B.AREA_END_DT OR A.CLIENTID = B.CLIENTID AND rnk = 1
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Left join on CID whihc brings backs all results and then I have created a sub query with a case statement to calcuate the areaid.

Comment: Update to show current SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a `Union` with sub queries.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT * DENSE_RANK() OVER PARTITION BY CID
    ORDER BY QUERY
    FROM (
        SELECT * '1' AS QUERY
        FROM TABLEA A
        INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.CID = B.CID
            AND A.START_DT BETWEEN B.AREA_START_DT
                AND B.AREA_END_DT
        WHERE 1 = 1

        UNION

        SELECT *
            ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (
                PARTITION BY A.CID ORDER BY B.AREASTART_DT DESC
                ) AS RNK '2' AS QUERY
        FROM TABLEA A
        INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.CID = B.CID
            AND RNK = 1
        WHERE 1 = 1
        )
    )
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND RNK = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `subquery` with *conditional* ordering

```
select a.CID, a.Start_dt, a.End_dt, 
       (select Areaid
        from TableB b 
        where b.CID = a.CID
        order by (case when b.AreaStart_dt = t.Start_dt 
                       then 0 else 1 end), AreaStart_dt desc
        LIMIT 1 
        ) Areaid
from TableA a;
```

Comment: Minor thing, but I don't think Oracle supports using LIMIT like that.